# setting up git and git-flow for 2 versions of a website. Remote access for some developers

Tags: git, web, versioning, git-remote, git-flow

I'm looking for the best deal to setting up git with the way I work, my dev team and I :
We woold like to use git for a website versionning with a remote webserver and some local developers. But we would have 2 states of the website online : one for production and one for develoments. We have already done a cp -fr of the root production website dir to another new dir and make virtualHosts with Apache to these 2 dirs.

I've found good things with git-flow, but I d'ont know exactly how to "link" the 2 website versions  with git and remotely access them indenpendently :
Must I "git init --bare" my online root website production version (with eventually the good post hook to protect .git files from http access and separate the dir)
then, must I do same thing for the develop version in the other dir (that it must be online to in order to test it), or must I just make a branch or clone with git ?

And how the local machine can acces all those 2 remote confs ?

We need to make some corrections on the develop remote online version for testing, and when it clean, put changes from the dev version to the prod version.

All local git dev workstations are ready with ssh acces (with pub-ssh-rsa.key in remote server :in /home/git/.ssh/....)